Error from gamlssCV and wp refering to data
When using gamlssCV or wp (and more) I get the following error and I have not been able to solve it:
In predict.gamlss(object, newdata = newdata, data = DatA,  ... :
There is a discrepancy  between the original and the re-fit
used to achieve 'safe' predictions
